# Is SharedPreferences suitable, or is there a better alternative?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sharedpreferences

I am trying to become familiar with android application development. I am trying to make a simple app to learn the basic skills, but I am not sure how to handle this part of the app. Therefore I need advice about how to go further.

I have a simple app with a button and a textview with 0 on it: the score. When the button is clicked, score goes up by 1 (by simple java code). When I close the app and restart, the score is 0 again.

What I want: When closing the app, the score must be saved, so that the same score appears on restart. For example, like that egg that you have to click on a million times. If several users had the app, everyone should have their own score (of course). The number should therefore really be linked to phone/account.

I already read about sharedpreferences. It sounds like what I'm looking for: Storing variables. However, I don't know if this is suitable for what I want to use it for. The score should never be lost for that specific phone/account. It may not be possible for the user to adjust the score himself (except by clicking on the button).

My question: Is sharedpreferences suitable for what I want to use it for, or is there a better alternative?

Comment: you can use SharedPreferences is best per your requirement.

Comment: @KanzariyaHitesh Thanks for the advice! So the score will never be 'forgotten' (and therefore reset) also not after weeks for example, the score cannot be adjusted by the user, and every telephone has its own 'sharedpreference'?

Comment: ya you should not change in sharedpreference until you can not done uninstall app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SharedPreferences` is used to store small pieces of data locally on your device. So, if the user *Uninstall the app or Clears App data*, the the data you store in `SharedPreferences` will be cleared.

If you are okay about data being lost on **Uninstall/ Clear Data**, `SharedPreferences` is surely the best way to store such small piece of information as using an Online database is quite an overkill for such small piece of data.

> The score should never be lost for that specific phone/account.

But according to this, it seems like don't want to lose the data even if the user **Uninstall/Clear Data**, clearly you have to use a Cloud Database like **Firebase Real-time database/ Firestore**.

If you want users to Login/Sign Up, you have to use Firebase Auth otherwise, you can simply store data as **PhoneNumber : Score** key-value pairs on Firestore.

Hope it helps

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply! In fact, when the user chooses to uninstall the app it's no problem if the variables get lost. If that can't happen as long as the app doesn't get uninstalled, it's fine.

I read that SharedPreferences are in fact XML files. I don't have much experience with this yet. But is it not possible for the user to adjust the XML file, so that the SharedPreferences variable is also adjusted? In other words: Is it not possible that the score is changed in this way by the user? Are SP variables safe enough to not be adjusted in any other way than via the 'score up button'?

Comment: No. Shared Preferences file is stored in root directory of phone storage (`/data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME/shared_prefs`). So a user cannot view/edit the Shared preferences file of any app unless they root their phone.

Comment: Okay, great! Then I will use SharedPreferences for storing the score. Thanks for your help!